# JS Upload file to HTML File Element preserving the effects of a regular click

Tags: javascript, html, file, google-chrome-extension

How can I use javascript to upload an image to a specific HTML file element (for example, the dropzone on images.google.com)?

I have tried doing

```
fileElement.files = [myFile];
```

But that just uploads my file to the specific HTML file element, without triggering the normal effect of uploading to that file element (for example, triggering the actual google search of the image).

Comment: Maybe try dispatching a `dragend` event?

Comment: Or perhaps a `drop` event.

Answer (score 0):

Every website will need different fine tuning, but the basics will probably be the same:

You find the element where they expect the drag events to happen, you build a [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/) instance, and add your file in it, you trigger the possibly various events they expect.

So for https://images.google.com/ currently it would be

```
// a 300x150px transparent Image file, you will provide yours
const blob = await new Promise((res) => document.createElement("canvas").toBlob(res));
const file = new File([blob], "myfile.png");

const dT = new DataTransfer();
dT.items.add(file);

// Google Image expects a dragenter event first
const dragenter = new DragEvent("dragenter", {dataTransfer: dT, bubbles: true});
document.dispatchEvent(dragenter);
// let the DOM update (they do apparently not do it synchronously)
setTimeout(() => {
  const drop = new DragEvent("drop", {dataTransfer: dT, bubbles: true});
  document.querySelector(".bdmI4").dispatchEvent(drop);
});
```